# modify source Data in collapsing header - cannot borrow X as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, egui

I'm new to Rust and
I can't get my head around a current borrowing issue I have with egui and rust
(or maybe what I wan't to do is not possible).

I wan't a List of Items, that are displayed as Collapsable Items.
Special should be that there should be a button in the collapsable that adds/modifies the Item list.

I've made a simple sample (based on https://github.com/palmxintreo/egui_template) :

```
pub struct TemplateApp {
    // Example stuff:
    labels: Vec<String>,
}

impl Default for TemplateApp {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            // Example stuff:
            labels: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl TemplateApp {
    /// Called once before the first frame.
    pub fn new(cc: &eframe::CreationContext<'_>) -> Self {
        Default::default()
    }
}

impl eframe::App for TemplateApp {
    /// Called each time the UI needs repainting, which may be many times per second.
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        // Put your widgets into a `SidePanel`, `TopPanel`, `CentralPanel`, `Window` or `Area`.
        // For inspiration and more examples, go to https://emilk.github.io/egui

        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            // The central panel the region left after adding TopPanel's and SidePanel's
            ui.heading("eframe template");

            for label in self.labels.iter_mut() {
                let id = ui.make_persistent_id(&label);
                egui::collapsing_header::CollapsingState::load_with_default_open(ui.ctx(), id, false)
                    .show_header(ui, |ui| {
                        ui.label("Head");
                        if ui.button("+").clicked() {
                            self.labels.push("One More".to_string());
                        }
                    }).body( |ui| {
                        ui.label("Body");
                }
            );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The compiler complains the following, which I get but don't know how to do it differently.

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self.labels` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/app.rs:35:38
   |
32 |             for label in self.labels.iter_mut() {
   |                          ----------------------
   |                          |
   |                          first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                          first borrow later used here
...
35 |                     .show_header(ui, |ui| {
   |                                      ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
38 |                             self.labels.push("One More".to_string());
   |                             ----------- second borrow occurs due to use of `*self.labels` in closure
```

Comment: You are iterating on the `labels`, and in that loop pushing elements in it. 
I haven't used egui at all, but from what I can see, you are only using the label to create the id. Therefore, you could try first making an iterator over your ids, and then use them. Something like : 
`let ids = labels.iter().map(|label| ui.make_persistent_id(&label)); for id in ids {/*  */}`
Here, you clearly specify that first use use the iteration on labels, and then it is available for mutation.
This is what comes from the top of my head and might be off the point however.